# How to share job queue in scrapy?

Tags: queue, scrapy

I want to share the url queue by different jobs of the same spider. The `JOBDIR` setting is just used for storing the state of a *single* job. Is there any solution for sharing the url queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at [scrapy-redis](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis) for this. It seems adequate.

Of course, this is if you don't mind adding Redis as dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'd like to use redis to keep the url queue. I'll adapt `scrapy-redis` to my project.